# Python : is coverage using skipped test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, skip

Here is a test :

```
@skip("my test is skipped")
def test_coverage():
    my_function()
```

My question is simple :

If i run my coverage, will `my_function` will be covered or not (considering my test is skipped) ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try it and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipped tests are not executed. Code that is not executed is not covered, by definition.

Demo; given a `coverage_demo` module:

```
def foo():
    var = "This function has is covered"

def bar():
    var = "This function is not"
```

and a `coverage_demo_tests.py` file:

```
from unittest import TestCase, skip
import coverage_demo

class DemoTests(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        coverage_demo.foo()

    @skip("No bar for us today")
    def test_bar(self):
        import coverage_demo
        coverage_demo.bar()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    unittest.main()
```

running this under coverage shows that line 5 in `coverage_demo` is not executed:

```
$ coverage run coverage_demo_tests.py
s.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

OK (skipped=1)
$ coverage report --include=coverage_demo\.py -m
Name               Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------
coverage_demo.py       4      1    75%   5
```

The `def` statements at the top level are always executed, but line 5 is the only line in the `bar()` function.

Comment: Okay ! I don't really know how does the coverage work !

Comment: @AntoineLB: that's explained in the [*How coverage works* section](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howitworks.html) of the project documentation.